# Adding Multiple Categories to a Business Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, categories

I'm trying to setup a rails application that has a Business model and a Category model. A business can have multiple categories and the categories can belong to multiple businesses.

Everything appears to be working properly and I am not getting any errors, except when trying to show the categories associated with a specific business nothing is displaying.

Below are my models, controllers and views. This is one of my first rails projects and am looking for a little help.

**business.rb**

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :category_id
  belongs_to :category

end
```

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :description
  has_many :businesses

end
```

**business_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @business = Business.find(params[:id])
  @categories = Category.where(:business_id => @business).all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @business }
  end
end

def new
  @business = Business.new
  @categories = Category.order(:name)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @business }
  end
end

def edit
  @business = Business.find(params[:id])
  @categories = Category.order(:name)
end
```

**business/_form.html.erb**

```
...

<div class="field">
    <%= f.association :category, input_html: { class: 'chosen-select', multiple: true } %>
</div>

...
```

**business/show.html.erb**

```
...

<ul class="tags">
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li><%= category.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

...
```

Comment: It would appear that there is a conflict between what you wrote regarding your models and what you showed with the code. You noted that a Business can have many Categories and that a Category belongs to a business. However, your models have the opposite of what you wrote (a business belongs to a category, which has many businesses). Would help to clarify which architecture is correct.

Comment: @craig.kaminsky I would like to assign multiple categories to a business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you want a business to have many categories, the relationships for your models should be updated as follows:

**Business**

```
def Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  attr_accessible :name, :etc
  # attr_accessible :category_id would not apply as the business model 
  # would not have this relationship
end
```

**Category**

```
def Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :business_id, :name, :description
  belongs_to :business
end
```

Then, in your controller you can can access the data:

**BusinessesController**

```
def show
  @business = Business.find(params[:id])
  @categories = @business.categories 
  respond_to ... 
end
```

Comment: now the only issue I'm having is that I can't mass assign a protected attribute (see image: http://cl.ly/image/3x0W0208023E/o). I'm trying to set the categories for each business from the business/edit view.

Comment: You should just be able to add `:category_id` to your `attr_accessible` expression in the Business model. That assumes you are using Rails 3.x (which is appears you are).

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much Craig for your patience and support!